# Update Query when username changes

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Here is a query I'm trying:

```
UPDATE toondb SET tusername = (select username FROM user WHERE userid='1') WHERE (select username FROM user WHERE userid='1') != (select tusername from toondb where tuserid= '1')
```

I whipped this up, hoping it'd work.  Let me try to explain, please.

I have one table called 'toondb'.  The toondb has different columns.
In this particular case, I am focusing on the 'tusername' and 'tuserid' column in this table.
The 'tusername' column contains the user's username, and the 'tuserid' column contains the user's userid.  When they submit info via the form, the 'tusername' and 'tuserid' columns are automatically populated with their username and userID on the forum.

Now, the other table, 'user', is where the info comes from.  There is a column 'userid' and 'username' in the 'user' table.
My userid is 1 and my username is whatever

So.. I have a row in the 'toondb' table for myself.  The userid is currently set to 1 for my row (as a userid never changes).  However, the username is set to 'Admin'.

Well, since my new username is 'whatever' and it's not 'Admin' anymore, I need to have a query that I can set to automatically run that will check the 'toondb' to make everyone's userid matches with their tusername.

e.g.
Checks toondb table
Sees userid is 1
Sees username is set to 'Admin'
Checks user table
Sees userid is 1
Sees username is now set to 'whatever'
Update's toondb to change their tusername to 'whatever' where their userid is '1'.

I know basic MySQL so I can ask stupid questions sometimes.. ;(

Just to clarify..
'tusername' and 'tuserid' are the columns in the **toondb** table
'username' and 'userid' are the columns in the **user** table
The values in the **user** table will always be accurate.  The value in the column 'username' in the **user** table must populate the value in 'tusername' column in the **toondb** table with the most recent info.

Comment: why having username in both tables when you can use JOIN

Comment: also, its bad style of using relational databases (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

as I commented, you should avoid having username in both tables, but if it is necessary, you can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to update usernames when they are changed

Comment: How can I do this?  I have username in both tables for a reason.  I really only need the UserID in both tables (and I can select username from user table where UserID='$userid') but that would be an extra query and may take longer for the php page to generate that way.  So, I am doing it this way :)  I basically just need to figure out a query that I can use to update their username on the 'toondb' table if it changed on the 'user' table but the UserID is the same.  Thx